# Proteção na requisição Ajax com php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Criei uma página, onde utilizo o método post com Jquery para outra, e retorno alguns cálculos.

Tentando proteger, fiz o seguinte na página:

**PÁGINA INDEX:**

***PHP***

```
<?php

    session_name('ola');
    $secure = false;
    $httponly = true;
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"],     $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['_token'] =  hash('sha512', rand(100, 1000).time().'ola');    
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['_token']; ?>" />
```

***JQUERY***

```
$.post("php/infowindows.php", {token : $("[name=token]").val()}, function(d){
            alert(d);       
});
```

**PÁGINA CÁLCULOS:**

```
<?php
    session_name('ola');
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['_token']) or !isset($_POST['token']) or $_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['_token']){
        die("Erro, morri!");
    }
    session_regenerate_id();
?>
```

Eu vi algumas postagens, daí resolvi criar meu próprio código. Diante deste, é possível dizer que ele esta "prevenindo" contra ataques CSRF?

Comment: basicamente sim.. protege mas não garante nada pois o token pode ser visto no código html

Comment: @Daniel suponhamos que eu codifique o valor do input hidden, e quando receber na outra pagina, codifico identico a session... Isso que você  quis dizer?

Comment: Não faz diferença  o token estar encriptado pois é possível obter o token apenas lendo o ćodigo html. Mas também não estou dizendo que não tenha utilidade. É sempre bom usar...  Mas na verdade nem se faz necessário dessa forma pois basta identificar se existe a sessão. Não precisa colocar num campo hidden um valor que já está na sessão. Algo mais seguro é fazer um mix com cookie e técnicas de  "reciclagem" do session id. A ideia é dificultar ações maliciosas ou não autorizadas.

Comment: @DanielOmine Eu acho que esta visão pode estar equivocada em relação da checagem da session. Você diz que tem utilidade, eu acredito que tenha na seguinte posição: Se eu apenas checar, terei o seguinte problema, a pessoa abre um página e como é gerado a `SESSION`, se ele abrir a segunda página, consegue acessar ela gerar error, ou seja, diretamente pela segunda ele acessa os dados. O que acha disso?

Comment: @DanielOmine Estou aqui pensando, irei adicionar uma session com o valor dos dados pessoais do PC e navegador... daí comparo na outra página, caso for diferente não entra...

Comment: Depende de como implementar (no caso do token).  O importante é que exista um ponto de início onde é obrigatório o usuário iniciar e fazer então a requisição. O que comentei sobre o token estar num hidden field é que isso apenas facilita para burlar pois até um bot conseguiria ler o hidden field e enviar a requisição. Obviamente que se for direto para a "segunda página" onde recebe os dados, será emitido erro pela falta do token. Para driblar isso basta ler automaticamente na primeira página qual o token. Com o token em mãos basta requisitar. Sacou?

Comment: @DanielOmine Como eu faria para não haver o token, ou evitar que o bot leia este?

Comment: há diversas técnicas sem captcha e muito eficientes para coibir bots. Uma das técnicas consiste em executar um processo em javascript no retorno do resultado da requisição.   A lógica nisso considera que a maioria dos bots nao interpretam ou renderizam a página (html, css, js). Nesse retorno é que faria a validação final da requisição. Como um bot não vai interpretar o javascript do retorno, a validação não se completa.. bingo!  rsrs... enfim.. é apenas uma de várias  técnicas para casos onde o uso de captcha não é muito viável. Podemos dizer que é uma gambiarra, mas é eficiente.

Comment: Existe um nome para este processo, conhece algum código que posso analisar?

Comment: CSRF protection.